# Does a puddle of Seafoam cleaner indicate a vacuum leak?

Tags: ford, misfire, throttle, taurus

Engine is "skipping", cutting out or what seems like a misfire (?) every once and a while.

(Even more so when the AC is on).

To start, did the SeaFoam throttle body cleaner, as shown here:

- [How to clean a gasoline fuel injection air intake with Sea Foam Spray](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O5N_Z1W6mho)

As far as I know, the hose was back on tight all around during the process.

When finished, removed the plastic tube without removing the whole hose and re-tightened. Upon moving the car, noticed what seemed like 4-8oz or maybe half the can of the fluid, below that area on the ground.

I can't tell if this somehow it left over after and spilled out... but not sure if that is really possible or if that much would still be sitting there.

Does it indicate a vacuum leak and perhaps a clue to my original issue....or somehow screwed up the cleaner process?

-2004 Ford Taurus SES DOHC

Comment: "Does it indicate a vacuum leak" No.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't just the A/C drain? Did you smell/feel what was on the ground to see if it truly was SeaFoam or just water?